# What's the name of this in PHP?

Tags: php, oop, arguments, type-declaration

I've come across the following method signature:

```
public function register(ServiceProviderInterface $provider, array $values = []){}
```

I don't understand the part that reads `ServiceProviderInterface $provider`. Can someone please explain what it does?

Comment: The variable passed to the function as the first argument (`$provider`) must be an object instance of class `ServiceProviderInterface`. http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Answer (score -1):

The text before `$provider` specifies what should the argument be. In this case it should be an instance of `ServiceProviderInterface`. Read more about type declaration here:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration